# Bessel function with shifted argument

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, generating-functions

Is there any standard practice which may represents $J_m(a\pm kx)$ in terms of $J_m(kx)$ where $a$ is any constant and $m$ is integer $>-1$

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it can work !

use the addition formula for bessel function :

[image]

where, $m>-1$

and the addition formula is :

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRZvE.jpg) [image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgVMI.jpg)  [image]

the hint is to use the fourier expansion of $J_{m}(x)$ as follow :

$J_{m}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$$\int_{-\pi}{\pi}$$e^{ixsin\xi}e^{-im\xi}d\xi$

where, $e^{ixsin\xi}=\sum{J_{m}{(x)}}z^{m}$